mysqli_connect: authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
I have PHP Version 8.3.7 installed and running according to phpinfo. I attempt a connection to a MYSQL 8 database and receive the message:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

From what I have found online, PHP 8.3 should know how to handle "caching_sha2_password". The only work-around I see is to force the use of mysql native password that has been recently deactivated from mysql. As I understand it, using the SHA authentication is the solution of the future. Hence, I would rather had it working than resorting to a work-around using an obsolete feature.
I have not seen anything explaining that PHP had to be configured in a particular way for this  work. I am ready to bet that I am missing something obvious...
phpinfo states: 8.3.7 Client API library version mysqlnd 8.3.7
The error message is:

Fatal error:** Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in /[...]/testSO01.php:13 Stack trace: #0 /[...]/testSO01.php(13): mysqli_connect() #1 {main} thrown in /[...]/testSO01.php on line 13


Does this answer your question? php mysqli_connect: authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

@Olivier The answer there says it was fixed in 7.4. So it should still be fixed in PHP 8.

This does not answer my problem. In fact it states "So the problem is when you are using latest MySQL (v8.+) with old PHP ( 7.3.x and earlier) that does not have support for caching_sha2_password you might get similar issue": I use Mysql8 and php 8.3; hence, I should not have any problem... This is what puzzles me.

Then please add ini_set('display_errors', 1); and run again. Or at least provide exact error message from error log.

In the code I posted only 13 lines. Why there is 22 in your file? Don't get me wrong. I just want your error message to be consistent with other output. Can you also run it from terminal?

Because instead of your call line to mysqli_connect, I had copy-pasted my call with first definition of variables... Now, the code run is exactly yours except that the blank line at the beginning is replaced by ini_set('display_errors', 1); I updated the output according to the current run.

this looks very strange. I would have thought that you are running into the usual situation with multiple php/and or mysql versions installed, but in case you have all this output on the same page I am out of ideas. Cannot think a scenario when it can be even possible. Though I am still thinking the issue is something related

Thanks for trying to help. I checked the php versions. I had two installed, because of dependences. I removed php8.3 to have only php8.2, but the symptoms are the same. I find a single mysqld program...

and what port this mysqld program is bound?

It seems to me that mysqld is not listening on any port (if this is possible). The following command (on MacOS) produces an empty output: lsof -i -P -n | grep -i mysql

"PHP 8.3 should know how to handle "caching_sha2_password". 
This is not really correct. PHP natively doesn't know how to connect to MySQL. The connection is done by a MySQL driver (eg. pdo_mysql)
Your plugin may be disabled in mysql, or for the user.
Login to mysql console, and see if the plugin is active.
mysql -u root -p

In mysql CLI,
SHOW PLUGINS;

# See if the plugin is active for the user:
SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user WHERE plugin = 'caching_sha2_password';

There are few things to check.

Is the mysql service running?
Is the caching_sha2_password active in MySQL?
Is the caching_sha2_password authentication assigned to user?
Are the username/password correct?
Does the mysql driver (eg. pdo_mysql) support caching_sha2_password?


Given most of these bullet points don't make any logical sense, such as "Is the mysql service running" (Who would return this error otherwise?), "Is the caching_sha2_password active in MySQL" (SAME as above, it is LITERALLY requested by MySQL), "Are the username/password correct" (the problem is irrelevant to that), I assume this entire text has been written by AI. Which is not allowed on Stack Overflow

So you conveniently decide to ignore the first part of the suggestion and focus on the checklist, and make an assumption it's generated by AI?
The question seems like asked from a junior who doesn't have a lot of experience. The checklist is given to check the things that can go wrong during troubleshooting this issue, based on my experience.
It's not constructive to attack someone's answer by concluding it's AI. If you have a better answer to help the author, please answer.

The first part is even more questionable. The error message says "authentication method unknown to the client" and then you are suggesting that "Your plugin may be disabled in mysql" which doesn't make logical sense.
